# how does ${pageContext.request.contextPath} work locally and remotely?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

How does  `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` work locally and remotely ?

Comment: Check your link again and Update your question with what you have tried please

Answer (score 0):

in both cases it will return you context of your deployment.